# Clicking Icon on Button Triggers Both onClicks (Button & Icon) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-icons

I have a `Button` component (`bootstrap-react`) that has a `X` icon on one end of the button. Both the `Button` and `X` components have a `onClick` handler defined.

However, when a user clicks on the `X` icon, both the `onClick` functions of both components are triggered. How do we ensure that only the `X` icon's `onClick` is triggered when the icon is clicked?

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { X } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';

function MyButton({onClick}) {
    const handleRemoveClick = () => {
        console.log('Clicked on icon')
    }

    return (
        <Button variant="light" onClick={onClick}>
            <span className="btn-text">Hello</span>
            <X fill="#aaa" onClick={handleRemoveClick} />
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the event object when the `X` button is clicked so that the event stops propagating.

```
const handleRemoveClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('Clicked on icon')
}
```